# Threadsafety of CDI Beans

Tags: jsf-2, scope, thread-safety, cdi

i have a question about injecting classes in a CDI managed JSF bean (RequestScoped) and if those injected classes are thread safe during the RequestScope.

Maybe its best to show the example code first:

----------------- JSF Bean, using CDI ------------------

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
...

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class DemoBean {

    @Inject
    LocalService localService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        localService.reloadCache();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return localService.getName();
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return localService.getAge();
    }

}
```

----------------- Service, using CDI ------------------

```
@Named
public class LocalService {

    private String name;
    private String age;

    public void reloadCache() {
        name = null;
        age = null;
        name = // slow SQL on remote Service, that needs to be cached
        age = // slow SQL on remote Service, that needs to be cached
    }

    public String getName() {
        // do some work, e.g. logging
        return name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        // do some work, e.g. logging
        return age;
    }
}
```

The JSF Bean "DemoBean" uses the "LocalService" class to get data from a DB (through remote EJB, but that shouldn't matter here). In the "LocalService" class, I want to cache the SQL results during a request for two reasons:

- the performance of the SQL query is poor (many joins, many data, ...)
- JSF Lifecycle: I don't want to execute the SQL query on every of the 6 JSF-Lifecycles

How does the injected "LocalService" class behave, if many JSF Beans (many concurrent calls to the JSF page) use it at the same time? Is the injected "LocalService" instance shared by other threads and thus not thread safe?

If this is the case, how can I make the Service thread safe?

e.g. (in LocalService)

```
Thread1: call reloadCache()
Thread1: call getName()

Thread1 is interrupted in the middle of getName() by Thread2

Thread2: call reloadCache()

Thread2 is interrupted in the middle of reloadCache() -> name is null

Thread1: continue execution of getName() and return name -> which is null at this moment -> very bad
```

This example is a very simplified version of my code, but I hope it made my question understandable

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default scope for a CDI bean in which the scope hasn't been explicitly declared is `@Dependent`. Going through [the javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/context/Dependent.html) for this annotation will show you that in your particular case, each instance of `DemoBean` is guaranteed to have it's own instance of `LocalService`.

> Any instance of the bean injected into an object that is being created by the container is bound to the lifecycle of the newly created object.

I read this as an instance is created for each newly created `DemoBean` and is destroyed at the same time (this might prove expensive for you in the long run)

Unrelated to your question: **Denormalize**. If you find yourself making too many hops to reach data, that is the simple and straightforward answer to the problem of excessive joining and the associated performance cost. But you probably already know this.

Comment: The only thing I would add to this is that you're actually not caching anything here because the other bean is `@RequestScoped`. As soon as that request is done that bean, and any dependent beans injected into it will be destroyed. Look for something longer such as `@ConversationScoped` or `@SessionScoped`.